# How to docker container logs to a local file?

Tags: docker, logging, docker-swarm

I need to look up into docker logs for some days ago and checking by `docker service logs SERVICE | grep WHAT_I_NEED` takes forever so I want to download the container logs from docker swarm and check those locally. I found that the container logs in Swarm can be found by:

> docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $INSTANCE_ID

but I can't find a way to download the log from the location.

Doing: `docker cp CONTAINER_ID:/var/lib/docker/containers/ABC/ABC-json.log ./` tells me that the path is not present. I understand that this path is in Swarm but then how to get the log from the container itself? Or is there another way to copy this file directly to a local file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running this one from your terminal:

```
docker logs your_container_name 2> file.log
```

This will redirect the container logs to the local file **file.log**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but isn't it possible to get the file directly as it is in docker?

Comment: Yes the log file actually exists locally in your machine where docker is running and doing a "docker inspect container_name" will fetch you the logpath. Using that logic I tried the following and was able to retrieve the file you referred:

**`cp \`docker inspect container_name | jq -r .[].LogPath\` .`**
this will copy the log file as it is in your current location (referred by '.' at the end of the command). You may give your choice of loaction also.
**Note**: since the log file exists locally, no need to use docker cp. Simple cp will do the trick. :-)

Comment: I get a permission denied doing cp directly, maybe I don't have rights. However I am marking your answer as right as it really does the trick

Comment: Thanks. Try using the command with **sudo** if you don't have direct permission.

Comment: Exactly what I've looked for! `2>` did the trick :)

Comment: file.log has been created but 0 byte

Comment: I’m curious: why did `docker` choose to write the logs to stderr instead of stdout?